# Import new (latest) .csv file into existing Google spreadsheet automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I receive a new CSV file every hour in my Google Drive.
I need my spreadsheet updated with the data in the latest CSV file after it has been received in the Google Drive folder.

The files coming into the folder has a unique name for each new one according to date and time.
For example: FileName_date_24hourtime.csv
FileName_20190524_1800.csv then FileName_20190524_1900.csv etc.

Firstly I'm not sure what the best approach is:

1. simply with a formula (probably not possible with not knowing the exact filename?) like =IMPORTDATA
2. a google script to find latest .csv file and automatically import as soon as file was added to Google Drive folder

Any assistance will be great!

The .csv file:
.csv file contains 28 rows and data should be split by ;
.csv file looks like this:
NAME;-63.06;-58.08;50.62;-66.67;-80.00
NAME;-61.82;-56.83;-50.55;-77.78;-70.00
NAME;-57.77;-50.21;52.88;-77.78;-70.00
NAME1;-57.69;-61.48;-55.59;-55.56;-60.00
NAME2;-61.62;-53.79;50.34;-66.67;-70.00
NAME3;-54.62;-54.57;-52.22;55.56;-60.00
... with total of 28 rows

Data should go to "Import_Stats" sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach here would be a script with a trigger that runs a function that performs data import to a spreadsheet.

Create a time-based trigger with 1-hour offset:

```
function trigger() {
  var trg = ScriptApp.newTrigger('checkFiles');
      trg.timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
}
```

Create function that checks files in a folder (e.g. "checkFiles").

```
function checkFiles(alreadyWaited) {
  //get spreadsheet and sheet;
  var id = 'yourSpreadsheetId';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Import_Stats');    

  var folderId = 'yourIdHere'; //folder by id is the simplest way;

  //get folder and files in it;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files       = folder.getFilesByType('text/csv');
  var filesImport = folder.getFilesByType('text/csv'); //fetch files again;

  //try to fetch number of files;
  var scriptProps = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var numFiles = scriptProps.getProperty('numFiles');

  //count current number of files;
  var numCurr = 0;
  while(files.hasNext()) {
  var f = files.next();
  numCurr++;
  }

  //if this is the first time, save current number;
  if(numFiles===null) { 
    scriptProps.setProperty('numFiles',numCurr);
  }else {
    numFiles = parseInt(numFiles);
  }

  if(numFiles===null||numFiles===(numCurr-1)) {

    //get today and reset everything except hours;
    var today = new Date();
        today.setMinutes(0);
        today.setSeconds(0);
        today.setMilliseconds(0);      

    //iterate over files;
    while(files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();

      //get file creation date and reset;
      var created = file.getDateCreated();
          created.setMinutes(0);
          created.setSeconds(0);
          created.setMilliseconds(0);

      //calculate offset, equals 0 for each file created this hour;
      var offset = today.valueOf()-created.valueOf();

      if(offset===0) {
        //perform data import here;
        var data = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();

        //ignore empty files;
        if(data!=='') { 
          //split data in rows;
          var arr = data.split('\r\n');

          //resplit array if only one row;
          if(arr.length===1) {
            arr = data.split('\n');
          }

          //append rows with data to sheet;
          arr.forEach(function(el){
            el = el.split(';');
            sh.appendRow(el);
          });
        }          
      }

    }

  }else {
    //if never waited, set minute to wait, else add minute;
    if(!alreadyWaited) {
      alreadyWaited = 60000;
    }else {
      alreadyWaited += alreadyWaited;
    }

    //if waited for 10 minutes -> end recursion;
    if(alreadyWaited===600000) {
      Logger.log('Waited 10 minutes but recieved no files!');
      return;
    }

    //wait a minute and recheck;
    Utilities.sleep(60000);
    return checkFiles(alreadyWaited);
  }      
}
```

And this is what should happen:

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, the trigger and check files makes sense thank you!
I will update the question with .csv details.

Comment: Glad I could help - see the updated sample code with an export logic added (assuming you need new data to be added and not rewrite the older one - the logic for updating existing rows is a bit different).
Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! The code looks perfect from my understanding.
However, after adding the folder, spreadsheet etc. ID's nothing happens when I run it even with the .csv file in folder.

Comment: I have also created a fresh .csv file but still no import happening into sheet

Comment: Hm, works fine for me - what does the project trigger say about successful / failed executions? Btw, do you recieve new csv fies at an excact time or there are some +- deviations? As for the no-import issue - does it happen on a single checkFiles() run from the script project edtior?

Comment: I guess there might be a slight delay at times... file will never be received before the hour bur from the hour it might be delayed by up to 5min max...

Comment: Running checkFiles() single run does not produce any data to the sheet Import_Stats

Comment: Sorry, you were right in code, it works if I go change the files creation attributes to exactly on the hour. My fault not mentioning it might be slightly delayed at times. the creation should be max delayed my a minute, but when the file arrives in the Google Drive folder might be delayed with 5min max...

Comment: As for the delay, thanks - I'll modify the answer to account for it - as your file might come in a min. later, hourly trigger may not catch the file until the next hour (and if you want to listen to a file add event, a much more complex handling is req.)
Please, do clarify one thing - can the csv file be created in the previous hour and delivered this hour (e.g. 12:59 created, 13:01 added)?

Comment: Also, the data is not splitting in rows. At the moment it all goes into one row.

Comment: .csv is only created every hour automatically (might have slight delay, but never before the hour), so it's the .csv of the current hour that should be updated to the sheet. 
So for example 13:00 or 13:01 a csv file was created on another server, thereafter it was automatically uploaded to Google Drive folder and might have arrived anytime between 13:00 to 13:05. This .csv data should then be imported to sheet as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you please, add a link to a csv file you are trying import? From your question, I assumed that you have 28 rows of data, each row formatted like 1;2;3;4;5 - see the updated answer for an example

Comment: Example of .csv file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13PKrqs1pzPLUjUKEn_sfI2wLtC0WaoCS

Comment: Thanks! I see the issue - your files should be split differently, let me check and I will update the answer!

Comment: I've added an additional check for csv file rows split by newlines (\n) without carriage return, works with your file for me - let me know if this is the case for you as well (will update the trigger a bit later).
Btw, if you have control of the API that creates this csv files you should consider deploying the script as a web app with a `doPost()` func and send a request to it from the server as soon as the file is created to trigger import, thus eliminating the arrival issue

Comment: Perfect, this is brilliant! It works exactly as expected.
It's such a useful script I hope others will benefit also :)

Comment: Great! Please, see the updated answer - `Utilities.sleep` allows to pause script execution up to 5 mins - if you do not have control over the API and the delay is at max 5 mins as you say, the script will trigger each hour, then wait 5 mins to account for the delay and only then execute import (it can be upgraded even further to save number of csv files to a `PropertiesService` storage to check whether or not to sleep)
Hope so too :)

Comment: Yes unfortunately I have no control over the program that creates initial .csv but your solution is great to allow for any possible delay.
Thank you again I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: Don't mention! Btw, check the updated answer, I've added an advanced handling that makes script to check for new files each minute for 10 minutes after it is triggered (assuming you do not intend to delete csv files) - you can configure it to do more checks, but beware the quotas